# How to draw graphs in react native with SQL data?

Tags: react-native

I'm looking for tool to draw graphs with react native and SQL data.

Please if you know any way or you have any code source of an example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts) for data representations. It has very good models in advance way with a good community support. But the SQL data processing part have to do in your app. According to the your requirements the data representation could be customizable.